# Bootable USB showing operating system not found

Tags: liveusb

Good Morning,

I have been trying to format my PC from yesterday and when i boot from USB,it shows a black screen and nothing happens after that.

The same USB i tried on a laptop and the windows installation page booted properly from the usb.

I also formatted my USB and then made bootable.

What can be the problem with my computer specifically.Please do help me.

Comment: are you in the right boot mode? (UEFI vs Legacy)

Comment: how do i do that ? or check the same ?

Comment: The boot mode is Legacy  as it was intended to be i guess.